# Forwarding touch events & maintaining momentum in android

Tags: android, listview, scroll

I have two views side-by-side which need to scroll in-synch with each other. Problem is, the second view is a ListView, so I can't just slap them both in a ScrollView and have done with it.

I've managed to set up scroll forwarding by creating an ObservableScrollView and listening for scroll events, then trying to scroll the ListView by the same delta using ListView.scrollListBy

Problems are:
- The ListView doesn't refresh its content when I use scrollListBy(int y)
- When I reach the bottom of either view, any momentum stops. How can I maintain momentum across the two views so that when I scroll the left hand view and it reaches the bottom, the list on the right keeps scrolling down?

Comment: I have same issue with this, do you find out? I found that a touchlistener absorbed the touch event so that parent cant receive it.

Answer (score 1):

I solved.

make:

1.ParentView as (or extend) `NestedScrollView`

2.ChildView.`NestedScrollingEnabled` = `false`

so the parent are fling, by even fling on child.